# Difference between Height and Max/Min height

Tags: silverlight

In Silverlight what is the difference between Height and Max Height or Min Height, and same in Width case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Height will only set the height of the object, but max or min height lets the user to stretch the control till max height, if max height is not set, the control's height can be stretched infinitely, and so as the case in Width..

Note: all controls cannot be stretched, so they dont require to set max min height or width, ex - button Control

Answer (score 0):

Setting the height value will simply fix whatever object to that height. 
Setting the max height will allow the object to grow but only to the max height.

Same with width.